# the set of linear transformations.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

Let S={T:$\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$:T is a linear
transformation with T(1,0,1)=(1,2,3), T(1,2,3)=(1,0,1)} .Then S is

(a) A Singleton Set

(b) A finite set containing more than one element

(c) A countable set

(d) An uncountable set

MY APPROACH: 
T(1,0,1)=(1,2,3)$\Longrightarrow$T(e$^{1}+e^{3})$=(e$^{1}+2e^{2}+3e^{3})$
$\Longrightarrow$T(e$^{1})$+ T(e$^{3})$=e$^{1}+2e^{2}+3e^{3}Similarly,$T(e$^{1})$+2T(e$^{2})$+3T(e$^{3})$=e$^{1}$+e$^{3}$

I cant think more than this

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. What are your thoughts on this ?

Comment: I only know the  answer,not the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A geometrical way to look at it is take the midpoint of given input points as origin and consider any axis through that origin perpendicular to the line joining two points and revolve the space around that axis by 180 degrees. And you can make such uncountable infinite axes. So the set S Is uncountable set.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint/Solution:** A linear transformation is determined by its values on a basis,hence $S$ is uncountable.(Of course you need to fill some details)

Comment: and how will you determine action on basis

Comment: @KisalayTripathi: Recall that any linearly independent set can be extended to a basis and proceed by noting that $\{(1,0,1),(1,2,3\}$ is linearly independent.